# Using database cursor instead of skip and limit

Tags: java, database, xodus

I'm not sure if the Cursor defined [in this Xodus ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-229) is the typical database cursor or not, but is there a way to support database cursors with Xodus?

For example, instead of the normal skip/limit approach, a cursor can be used to resume retrieval of the results.

Is there a way to use a cursor instead of skip and limit with Xodus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Environments API there are aleady [cursors](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Environments#cursors). The ticket mentioned is about so called persistent cursors in the EntityStore API that could survive through changing transaction and even EntityStore close/open. It's very unlikely that this feature would ever be implemented.

Comment: So cursor only works within the same transaction context? So it's not usable for pagination in a user interface?